# Can I install Azure Devops Build Agent on Azure Virtual Machine?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Trying to move self-hosted TFS to Azure DevOps.

We have a bunch of custom software installed on our build machine as well as custom build procedures, we do Windows app builds and create an MSI file.

I am pretty sure this is possible but want to make sure before telling upper management - can we create an Azure Virtual Machine and install the Build Agent software (and all our custom software), and do our app builds from there?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZM8F.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. As long as the machine can establish a network route to `dev.azure.com`, it'll work fine.

If you need your VMs to have access to on-prem resources or be joined to your internal domain, you'll have to establish a VPN connection.